# Altium "Where Used" search in multiple projects

Tags: altium

Our design repo has multiple projects (SVN controlled) and we use an on-site library of parts.

I'm looking for a way to search all of our projects for instances of a specific part. The intent is to identify projects that contain parts that have gone obsolete, then kick off tasks to add a suitable alternate for all projects.

I've seen reference to "where used" in Altium Vault, but can it be done without?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a number of ECAD systems over the years, but never Altium specifically. If there isn't a built-in way to get what you want, here's another approach.

I assume you can get a BOM for each assembly in tabular form (e.g., a spreadsheet or equivalent). You just need to add a column to the BOM that contains the assembly ID on every line. Then mash all of the BOMs together into one big table and sort on the part ID column.

Comment: Thanks, good option. I'm going to give that a shot. I do have an Outputs directory with locked down pdf BoMs which I'm checking to see if they are easily searchable. May need to restrict search to internal .xls's though... pdfs take a long time to search.